# Making sure neither email nor username is taken already

Tags: php, mysql

So I am trying to make sure both the entered email and the entered username isn't already taken. I'm not sure why it's not working, I've only managed to have 1 work at a time.

```
session_start();
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
```

-

```
$Email = $_POST['email'];
$Username = $_POST['username'];
```

-

```
$sqltwo = "SELECT Username FROM user WHERE `Username`='$Username'";
        $resulttwo = $con->query($sqltwo);

        if ($resulttwo->num_rows == 0) {
            $UsernameTaken = false;
         } else {
            $_SESSION['usravailability'] = "Username already taken." ;
            header ('location: index');
        }

    $sqlthree = "SELECT Email FROM user WHERE `Email`='$Email'";
        $resultthree = $con->query($sqlthree);

        if ($resultthree->num_rows == 0) {
            $EmailTaken = false;
         } else {
            $_SESSION['emlavailability'] = "Username already taken." ;
            header ('location: index');
        }


    if ($UsernameTaken == false && $EmailTaken == false) {
    echo 'not taken;
} else {
    echo 'taken';
}
```

I've also tried with

```
if ($UsernameTaken == false || $EmailTaken == false) {
    echo 'not taken;
} else {
    echo 'taken';
}
```

which didn't work either. I'm probably doing something very wrong, but I have no idea what.

Comment: Why don't you add the UNIQUE constraint to the email and username columns?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: `echo 'not taken;` that'll throw a parse error for one thing and you also didn't choose a database. This thing's also prone to a serious sql injection. Quite a few more things that should be done here btw, besides what I said.

Comment: Also `mysqli_connect` is procedural style, should be `new mysqli` since then you use OOP style, but it seems PHP is lenient in this regard..

Comment: In case you're interested in why the code you had didn't work, it seems that you aren't initializing either `$UsernameTaken` or `$EmailTaken` in the case where they are taken. They are therefore considered null, which is "==" false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler version in my opinion would be to have one sql statement:

```
$sqlquery = "SELECT Username, Email FROM user WHERE `Username`='$Username` OR `Email`='$Username`";
```

Then check if any rows are found and store that value in a new variable (ex. alreadyExists).

For the message, if any rows are found, check if the $Username variable matches the username in the row, then output a message that "the username already exists", else if the email matches, output that "the email already exists".

Like this you'll just have one query, reducing connections to the database and only one variable to check, 'alreadyExists'

Comment: So I've done it like this
`$sqlquery = "SELECT Username, Email FROM user WHERE `Username`='$Username` OR `Email`='$Username`";
            $emusr = $con->query($sqlquery);
        
        if ($emusr->num_rows == 0) {
echo 'do stuff';
} else {
            if($row['Username'] == $Username) {
                $_SESSION['usravailability'] = 'Username already taken.';
            }
            if($row['Email'] == $Email) {
                $_SESSION['emlavailability'] = 'Email already in use.';
            }
        }

`
Sorry about the mess

Comment: You will need to have a variable like this: $alreadyExists = $emusr->num_rows > 0; to check if already exists or not. Also it could be that you won't have just one row, but maybe two rows. Onw more thing is that the 'if($row['Email']' has to be an else if, so that it only checks once

Answer (score 1):

A few problems I see that can improve your script.

1st - Select a database before running your query

2nd - Sanitize the user input with prepared statements, or bare minimum use mysqli_real_escape_string.

3rd - As @CliveCiappara wrote in his answer, one query will suffice.

4th - Add an ' in your echo ( echo 'not taken'; )

```
session_start();
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);

$Email = $con->mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$Username = $con->mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);

$q = "SELECT Username, Email 
      FROM user 
      WHERE `Username`='$Username' 
      OR `Email`='$Email'";

$r = $con->query("$q");

echo ($r->num_rows === 0) ? "Not Taken" : "Taken";
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing a `'` after `not taken` (not properly terminating your string). Could this be related to your problem?